# How to implement Observable in native-script using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, nativescript

I just started learning native-script framework and I'm following the "Get Started with JavaScript" tutorial from the official website. I have a background in Java so I'm more familiar with typescript. I tried to replace all JavaScript code to the typescript equivalent.

So far everything is OK, but when I reached [Chapter three > 3.4: Adding a view model section](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/chapter-3#34-adding-a-view-model) , I got confused on how to implement the Observable in typescript. this is the code from the website:

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable");

var user = new observableModule.fromObject({
    email: "user@domain.com",
    password: "password"
});
```

And this is what I came up with:

```
import {Observable} from 'data/observable';
class User extends Observable {
    email = "user@domain.com";
    password = "password";
}

let user = new User();
```

When I tested it, it seems to work. Are the above codes equivalent or did I miss something?

Comment: you can try this way also https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/observable#mvvm-pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is the way to make an "object" observable. A different but also similar approach would be to make your entire "ViewModel" observable for example:

```
import { Observable } from "data/observable";

export class ViewModel extends Observable {    
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.set("propertyA", 42);
        this.set("propertyB", "some value");
    }

    public updatedValues() {
        this.set("propertyA", 3.14);
        this.set("propertyB", "some new value");
    }
}
```

after that if you set that `ViewModel` to be `bindingContext` of the Page you can do your normal bindings and any updates to the those properties of the `ViewModel` will be propagated to the view.

```
<Label text="{{ propertyA }}"/>
<Label text="{{ propertyB }}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir